# Term for central note in melody

Tags: theory, terminology

Is there a music theory term to describe when a melody revolves around one key repeated note?

For example, in a piece I am playing, the melody is: F C G C Ab C Bb C. Or, in my version of "spatial awareness" ( an exercise a lot of front ensembles seem to play) , we play a blues scale, but we play a C in between each note of the scale (Eb C F C F# C G C Bb C and so on).

So, in both of those situations, what would that C be called, if anything?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "revolves around". What is the key signature of this melody? Perhaps you are referring to the tonic note of the key.

Comment: The word "revolving" in the original question might be misleading, if it really is an alternating and non-sustained note then I've always known these as pedal tones.  So I've gone for Dom's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how you are using it, [pedal point/tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point) or [drone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(music)) may be the right terms for it.

A pedal point is typically a sustained bass note where the melody changes over it, but it can also be a repeated note between itself and other notes as shown in the example below similar to what you describe.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point#/media/File:Pedal_tone_example.png]

A drone is very similar in nature, however it is more to establish tonality and typically will be throughout an entire piece or section where as a pedal point is typically much shorter in nature.

Answer (score 0):

The “central tone” of your examples is either the root tone of the key tonic or the dominant:

> For example, in a piece I am playing, the melody is: F C G C Ab C Bb C.

This is the  scale of f-minor (F,G,Ab,Bb,C)  and it’s always turning to the 5th as changing tone, very usual in Baroque era, but also known in Classic music as *Alberti Basses*.

> Eb C F C F# C G C Bb C

This is a typical Blues pattern:

The root of the tonic of your Blues Scale can be considered as *pedal tone* like another answer says.

You may also know *Odyssea Beneziana* by **Rondo Veneziano**

[image]

Both features occurred already in the modes of Plain chant:

*The recitation tone, the repercussion note, the repercussa, the tenor, the tuba, or even the psalmodization sound is an important structural tone within the church modes.*

*In addition to the basic tone, the finalis, in the medieval tones systems there is always another tone, the recitative tone, a role in the melodic progression.  This sound is usually achieved at an early stage within a melodic section, and it is played more often than other tones.  In the psalm tones, the recitative tone is the tone on which much of the psalm text is recited.*

Source:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rezitationston